# disk usage calculation of macOS - counting duplicated entries?

Tags: macos, diskspace, du

I have a problem understanding the disk usage calculation of macOS. My disk-utiliy shows the following usage:

[image]

On the shell I get a similar picture

```
$ df -h
Filesystem       Size   Used  Avail Capacity iused     ifree %iused  Mounted on
/dev/disk1s7s1  233Gi  8.7Gi   35Gi    20%  356810 365211400    0%   /
devfs           197Ki  197Ki    0Bi   100%     682         0  100%   /dev
/dev/disk1s2    233Gi  2.0Gi   35Gi     6%    2289 365211400    0%   /System/Volumes/Preboot
/dev/disk1s4    233Gi  3.0Gi   35Gi     8%       4 365211400    0%   /System/Volumes/VM
/dev/disk1s6    233Gi   21Mi   35Gi     1%      20 365211400    0%   /System/Volumes/Update
/dev/disk1s5    233Gi  184Gi   35Gi    85%  932950 365211400    0%   /System/Volumes/Data
/dev/disk1s1    233Gi  1.1Mi   35Gi     1%     143 365211400    0%   /Volumes/MAC - Daten
map auto_home     0Bi    0Bi    0Bi   100%       0         0  100%   /System/Volumes/Data/home
```

To get the folders with more then 1 GB space usage I was running: `du -ht 1G / 2>/dev/null`. Counting space usage of the root and first level folders I get the following picture:

```
199G    /
109G    /System
 65G    /Users  
 18G    /Applications
1,8G    /Library
3,1G    /usr
2,4G    /private
```

summing up the first level folders gives me ~ 199,3G which suits to the 199G of root.

Taking a deeper dive in the sub folders of the `du` output, show me some duplicated entries, see example below. Currently I get the impression the system is counting space usage
twice, which would be wrong in my understanding. If I filter out the duplicated entries, my disk usage should be 109G, this is 90G less then stated by disk-utility, 199G.

*Is there an error in my reasoning regarding the disk usage (calculation)?*

Exmaples:

```
 65G    /System/Volumes/Data/Users
 65G    /System/Volumes/Data/Users/foobar
 13G    /System/Volumes/Data/Users/foobar/mail
 22G    /System/Volumes/Data/Users/foobar/Pictures
 13G    /System/Volumes/Data/Users/foobar/Pictures/2021
6,4G    /System/Volumes/Data/Users/foobar/Pictures/2022
2,6G    /System/Volumes/Data/Users/foobar/Pictures/2023

compared to:

 65G    /Users
 65G    /Users/foobar
 13G    /Users/foobar/mail
 22G    /Users/foobar/Pictures
 13G    /Users/foobar/Pictures/2021
6,4G    /Users/foobar/Pictures/2022
2,6G    /Users/foobar/Pictures/2023
```

---

```
 18G    /System/Volumes/Data/Users/foobar/Library
 11G    /System/Volumes/Data/Users/foobar/Library/Containers
3,9G    /System/Volumes/Data/Users/foobar/Library/Caches

compared to: 

 18G    /Users/foobar/Library
 11G    /Users/foobar/Library/Containers
3,8G    /Users/foobar/Library/Caches
```

---

```
2,5G    /System/Volumes/Data/usr
2,5G    /System/Volumes/Data/usr/local
2,0G    /System/Volumes/Data/usr/local/Cellar

compared to: 

3,1G    /usr
2,5G    /usr/local
2,0G    /usr/local/Cellar
```

---

```
 18G    /System/Volumes/Data/Applications
2,0G    /System/Volumes/Data/Applications/Docker.app
1,1G    /System/Volumes/Data/Applications/Google Chrome.app
1,7G    /System/Volumes/Data/Applications/Microsoft Excel.app
2,2G    /System/Volumes/Data/Applications/Microsoft Word.app
1,5G    /System/Volumes/Data/Applications/Microsoft PowerPoint.app

compared to: 

 18G    /Applications
2,0G    /Applications/Docker.app
1,1G    /Applications/Google Chrome.app
1,7G    /Applications/Microsoft Excel.app
2,2G    /Applications/Microsoft Word.app
1,5G    /Applications/Microsoft PowerPoint.app
```